# glpk and pcre not found (NIXOS)

Tags: nix, nixos, nixpkgs

I am trying to build my own nix-shell environment in my NixOS. I have 2 .nix file, default.nix and shell.nix, here's the configuration:

default.nix:

```
{ stdenv, haskellngPackages}:

let
  env = haskellngPackages (p: with p; [
        aeson
        bytestring
        conduit
        snap
        ghcjs
        text
        wai
        warp
        yaml
        haskell.packages.lts-4_01.ghc
        ]);

in
  stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "RiziLab";

buildInputs = [
  glpk
  pcre
  env
];

    STACK_IN_NIX_EXTRA_ARGS
       = " --extra-lib-dirs=${glpk}/lib"
       + " --extra-include-dirs=${pglpk}/include"
       + " --extra-lib-dirs=${pcre}/lib"
       + " --extra-include-dirs=${pcre}/include"
    ;
}
```

shell.nix:

```
{ pkgs ? (import <nixpkgs> {} ) }:

(import ./default.nix) {
  stdenv  = pkgs.stdenv;
  haskellngPackages = pkgs.haskellngPackages;
}
```

but when I do nix-shell, i got this error:

```
error: undefined variable ‘glpk’
```

from what I understand, the default.nix is only a function which will be called by the shell.nix, cmiiw. The question is:

1. Is there any error in my code?
2. I have used either `{nixpkgs ? (import <nixpkgs> {} ) }` and `{pkgs ? (import <nixpkgs> {})}` but still got the same error, is there any different between these two?
3. is it okay to exclude ghcwithPackages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glpk` not being defined in `default.nix` is the problem.
`glpk` path is `pkgs.glpk` but there is no `pkgs` in `default.nix` scope and `glpk` is not passed as a parameter to the function.

Also, there is no need to have 2 separate files, it is possible to group the whole in one file:

```
{ nixpkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}, compiler ? "lts-4_1" }:
let
  inherit (nixpkgs) pkgs;
  ghc = pkgs.haskell.packages.${compiler}.ghcWithPackages (ps: with ps; [
          aeson
          bytestring
          conduit
          snap
          # ghcjs # not a package but a compiler
          text
          wai
          warp
          yaml
        ]);
in
pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "RiziLab";
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [ ghc glpk pcre ];
  shellHook = "eval $(egrep ^export ${ghc}/bin/ghc)";
  STACK_IN_NIX_EXTRA_ARGS = with pkgs; 
      " --extra-lib-dirs=${glpk}/lib"
    + " --extra-include-dirs=${glpk}/include"
    + " --extra-lib-dirs=${pcre}/lib"
    + " --extra-include-dirs=${pcre}/include"
  ;
}
```

You can learn more about using haskell in nix in the [Nixpkgs manual](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#users-guide-to-the-haskell-infrastructure).